# PopUp that only closes on true

Tags: html, blogger

I need to create a popup that users cannot close except for when two checkboxes are marked.
The logic is as follows:

```
<form 
     action="#" 
     onsubmit="if(document.getElementById('agree').checked) + document.getElementById('agree2').checked{ return true; } else { alert(...code continues here...) 
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
```

Is there a way to encapsulate my snippet into a popup that opens itself and closes automatically?

Comment: Inlining javascript into html evil, especially like that. Use event listener instead